# How am I creating a default object from an empty value?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting this warning when I try to run my code:

> Creating default object from empty value (on line #24)

**Controller:**

```
public function createFields($tablename) {
    $this->load->model(array('Connection_model', 'Read_data_model'));       
    $posts = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    foreach ($posts as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value) && !empty($value) && isset($key) && !empty($key) && $key != 'submit') {
            $this->Read_data_model->isset_row('sender', $tablename, $key);              
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function isset_row($target, $table, $key) {
    $this->load->model('Connection_model');
    $query = $this->Connection_model->get_custom_db('sender')->get($table);
    foreach ($query->result() as $row->{$key}) { // This is line #24
        echo $row->{$key};
    }   
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use StdClass for empty object

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself. In the foreach loop it needs to be only `$row` instead of `$row->{$key}`.